# Is it beneficial to use restrict keyword in a CUDA kernel?

Tags: cuda

I came across a CUDA kernel declared as `__global__ void sample_kernel(float* __restrict__ input, float* __restrict__ output){...}`.

While it makes sense having the `restrict` keyword in regular C functions and related compiler optimizations it can bring, does it have any performance improvement by this declaration in this CUDA kernel?

I am asking this because CUDA by itself works by having multiple threads executing in parallel. What kind of optimization this keyword can bring among the already parallel threads?

Comment: Did you know that CUDA has a [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#restrict)?  The potential benefits don't depend on the number of threads.  And, the CUDA compiler is essentially a single thread compiler.  A CUDA kernel defines what a thread will do.   Finally, there is a CUDA-specific possible compiler optimization when a set of kernel argument pointers are sufficiently decorated: it can indicate to the compiler that it is self to use [a special caching load](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-5-x).

Comment: When you explicit restrict a pointer, you are telling the compiler that it doesn't need to worry about pointer aliasing. That allows for a whole range of caching optimizations which can be extremely effective at increasing performance. The restrict keyword is discussed in a good amount of detail in the programming guide. Please take the time to read it